# Writing to application internal storage - frequency limit?

Tags: android, storage, internal

I have an application which periodically receives files and saves them in the internal storage (i.e. data/data/app_name/files), sends them via email, and finally deletes them. It is all working fine, but I'm wondering if there is a limit to how many times I can write to the internal storage. My current application repeatedly writes and deletes data - which is required. Would it be better to use the cache memory?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I'm wondering if there is a limit to how many times I can write to the internal storage

Not really. Eventually, the flash cells will wear out. Try not to do tens of thousands of I/O operations per day, and you should be OK.

> Would it be better to use the cache memory?

Cache storage is on the same internal storage as is the internal storage that you are already using.